# Android Edittext can not move cursor to the Special position(such as the end of first line)

Tags: android, cursor, android-edittext, move

**strong text** Android `edittext` widget can not move cursor to the end of line (such as at the end of the first row) when more than one line.
We can uses `Selection.setSelection` to set cursor to some position, but we can not move it to the end of first line.

Comment: you did add some padding in your edittext some where in xml file or in code .check it out ...........

Comment: I do it as you say ,but still can not move it,thanks all the same !

Comment: code :  <EditText
        android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        />